# Spring Unit/Intergration Testing setup

Tags: java, spring, junit, log4j

I didn't write unit or integration testing but now I am trying. I am having a hard time setting up the environment.

I have my application context under WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
and in my applicationContext.xml, it has a reference to a properties file for DB user/pass, LDAP host, etc

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/dev.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have another properties for log4j config (diff config for DEV/Staging/Production). `${webapp.root}` is defined in web.xml

```xml
 <!-- log4j setting -->
    <bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${webapp.root}/${log4j.properties.location}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And now I am trying to put the following in a test class.

```
@Override
protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
   return new String[]{
            "file:trunk/code/web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",
        };
}
```

This references my xml correctly, but all the properties are screwed up.

I want to know the following:

- Is there a way to set up in the test class properly? If not, should I move these classes?
- How can I set up Log4j if there is a reference to webroot which only exist in a container?!
- What is the best practice of Spring config location?

Please Advise

Thanks

Comment: Did you have success? Share it.

Answer (score 6):

[This blogpost of mine](http://bozhobg.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/database-integration-testing-with-spring-jpa-junit-and-maven/) describes the basic steps to achieve your goal.

Note that the unit tests shouldn't know that you have a webapp-root - they are usually run without any servlet container started. So place the alternative config files in the test packages and try.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.  Each module has unit tests and a custom `test-application-context.xml` file that the unit tests refer to via Spring's `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.  It really is awesome being able to set up a context with whatever mock test fixtures I need for each Maven module in our project.  For integration testing each module has a different `integrationtest-application-context.xml` which brings in beans from all the dependent modules.

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing you should not be using the Spring application context. You should be testing all your spring beans and controllers individually as they are the individual units within the system. As they are POJOs it is easy to wire everything together programatically in your test case code. The also solves issues such as the location of the logging properties file as you can programatically specify a different path that does not rely on the webroot property.

The [testing chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) in the Spring Reference provides a good overview of how to approach unit and integration testing of applications that use Spring. It also provides details of the various support classes that Spring provides to help with writing unit and integration tests.

Comment: If you don't have an application context for your unit tests, then you can't use spring injection various beans into your test fixtures.  Wouldn't you then be missed an important aspect of testing?  Or should you do both?

Comment: I would say a test where you don't use an application context is a unit test as your are only testing that individual unit so it doesn't matter that the beans are being programatically injected.

If you use an application context I would say that is more like an integration test given you are explicitly testing how everything fits together.

Comment: @HDave I would say you should do both. Agree with Mark about what separates unit and integration tests. If you need to run with a context, you're not going as far as you can to get the speed of feedback that unit testing offers. On top of that, you're definitely not doing TDD. Not that you have to. Just saying...

Comment: I agree you should do both, but I don't agree that the mere presence of an application context means its an integration test instead of a unit test.  Perhaps it is a fine line, but I prefer to think of integration tests as involving more than one software module.  In my case, certain unit tests required certain mock test fixtures that are better and easier set up in a test application context.  That said, 90% of the time when people are saying they use a Spring application context when unit testing, they are wiring up beans from  other software modules...which is integration testing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use annotations to reference the necessary configuration from the tests, like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
     DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
     DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
     TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
     "file:../WebService/src/main/resources/application-context.xml",
     "file:../ServiceLayer/src/test/resources/ServiceLayer-dao-test-context.xml" })
public class MyTest {
     // class body...
}
```